# Configure audio interface buffer size for system use in windows 7

Tags: audio-interfaces, windows, sound-devices, latency

I was just wondering if there's any way to change te buffer size that my audio interface is using while its being used as the system's (W7) default audio device for domestic multimedia aplications like music in web browser(spotify, youtube, etc.).

I've tried to configure this in my audio interface's propoerties under windows device manager and windows playback device manager, whith no success.

I'm trying this because whenever I want to play music or video through my interface (in firefox) I usualy experience a lag, where playback stops for a while (about 1s) and then goes on. This keeps happening all the way through the video. I notice it specially with youtube, but it has also happed with other applications.I don't really know if this is caused by the buffer size or even if it makes any sense to talk about the buffer if ASIO is not being used.

I've got a Roland DUO-CAPTURE EX. Drivers installed. Works fine with ASIO in any DAW.

Comment: You may find it's not the buffer size that is the problem, but the combination of your disk IO and processor speeds.